# How to hide by default a div with "display: table-cell"?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a `div` with following style:

```
<div style="display: table-cell;
```

I would like to hide it at the beginning.

If I set `display: none` instead of `table-cell`, and latter with jQuery call `show()`, `div` will not behave anymore as a "table cell".

Can I apply `table-cell` and `none` together?

Comment: If you use the `hide` method to hide the element, instead of applying inline style on the element yourself - then `show` will be able to restore the previous value (otherwise it will just set `block`, and that's what destroys your table functionality here.) If that's not an option - then toggle your own class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use and toggle a class instead

```js
$("#bt").on("click",function() {
  $("#div1").toggleClass("hide");
})
```

```css
.tbcell { display: table-cell; }
.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bt">Click</button>
<div id="div1" class="tbcell hide">This is table-cell and hidden to begin with</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use jquery or plain js to set a specific display property value on an element.

Check below both options

```js
// jquery
// $("#myDiv").hide()
// $("#myDiv").css("display", "table-cell")


// plain js

const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv") // or other selector
const btn = document.getElementById("clickMe")
myDiv.style.display = "none"

clickMe.onclick = () => myDiv.style.display = "table-cell"
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="display: table-cell">
    table-cell
</div>

<button id="clickMe">change display</button>
```

Comment: I do not recommend using .css or style.display when it can all be handled by [toggling a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68996607/295783)

Comment: You would now have to change back to style.display="none" to hide again. That is so inelegant and cumbersome. Just toggling hide off and on keeps the table-cell

Comment: Why would i want to change back to display none ? :) The question was to have the div hidden by default and then change it back to table cell.  And what if you don't have access to CSS ? We can debate on ' elegancy ' a whole day. That's opinion based.

Comment: If you have access to write script, you can write css rules. And you are entitled to your opinion regardsless how many developers that share it ;)

Comment: ok. you know best. ' If you have access to write script, you can write css rules. ':) You mean like editing a stylesheet from javascript ? and that would be super elegant.

Comment: Well, there are a [LOT of libraries](https://css-tricks.com/a-thorough-analysis-of-css-in-js/) doing just that so perhaps yes

Comment: So, you would keep the `toggleClass`  solution. Even if you have to add those css rules inside the stylesheet using a library or from js ?  Instead of toggling the `display` property value from js directly ?

Comment: I have luckily never been in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggle` to class that apply the `table-cell`

```js
function show(){
 $('.special').toggle('showCell');
}
```

```css
.special{
display:none;
}
.showCell{
display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="special showCell">
hello
</div>
<button onclick="show()">click</button>
```

Comment: That is the same as [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68996607/295783) except you are using an inline event handler. That is not recommended

Comment: ho i did not see that you posted same answer the inline event only for example how to use `toggle`